# Can't get out of my while loop

Tags: java, string, while-loop, string-length, word-count

I was wondering if someone can tell me why my while loop is acting funny. When I input a 3 word phrase it should create an acronym. For a reason beyond my java understanding the while loop executes but then keeps executing even when the client inputs the right answer. Any idea why? I have read what seems million posts and watch youtube videos about it, but no clue.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ThreeLetterAcronym
{
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        //variables
        String phrase;
        int wordCount;
        String acronym;

        //input
        phrase = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a three word phrase.");
        String [] word = phrase.split("\\s+");
        wordCount = word.length;

        //loop for error when less than 3 words
            do
            {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error, you need to input a 3 word phrase to create a 3 letter acronym." + '\n' 
                    + "Please try again.");
                    phrase = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a three word phrase");
            }       
            while(wordCount !=3);

        //create acronym
        acronym = Character.toString(word[0].charAt(0)).toUpperCase() + 
                     Character.toString(word[1].charAt(0)).toUpperCase() + 
                     Character.toString(word[2].charAt(0)).toUpperCase();

        //output
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The phrase you inputed is " + "." 
        + phrase + "\nYour 3 letter acronym is " + acronym + ".");


    } 
}



enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop will fail if the user types 4 or more words.  Change `wordCount != 3` to `wordCount < 3` or be ready to handle longer phrases like *North Atlantic Treaty Organization*.

A `do-while` loop always executes at least once.  Here, where you are checking for errors, that's actually reasonable, but you are also never recalculating your `word` array, so the error condition persists.  You want logic like:

```
String[] words;  // words, not word.  There is more than one.
while (true) {
    // 1. Fill in the word array from the user's input.
    // 2. Check the input for errors.
    //     a. If there are none, break out of the loop with a break statement.
    //     b. Otherwise, show the error message.
}
// Create the acronym.  Try to use a loop for this too, as in:
StringBuilder acronym = new StringBuilder();
for (String word: words) {
    // Append to acronym.
}
// report acronym.
```

Finally, try not to do all your work in `main`.  Create a `ThreeLetterAcronym` object, give it instance variables and methods, and tell it to do the work.  Break up the work in `main` into smaller methods. Now, you can test those methods.

Comment: Variables 'word' and 'wordCount' are also never being checked once the do-while loop is being executed.  If the first input is anything other than three words it's an infinite loop :|

Comment: I believe I pointed that out, saying that *you are also never recalculating your word array*.  I didn't say, however, that he needed to recalculate *wordCount* too. I did my version in pseudo-code so the poster could have something to do.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is executing after entering a three-word phrase because, as Eric mentioned, a `'do-while'` loop will always execute at least once.  The best, simple solution to resolve that issue would be to use a `while` loop instead, as follows:

```
while(wordCount != 3)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error, you need to input a 3 word phrase to create a 3 letter acronym." + '\n' 
    phrase = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a three word phrase");enter code here
}
```

A `do-while` loop performs an action and then checks if it should perform that action again.  A `while` loop checks if it should perform an action first, which is what you want to be doing.

---

There are also some other significant issues that would be worth resolving at the same time.

Your variables `word` and `wordCount` are not being updated once the program enters your `do-while` loop.  If a user first enters a three-word phrase, they're fine.  If they enter a phrase of any other length the program will loop indefinitely.  Since the program is executing the logic inside the `do-while` loop only, and that does not include saving new words into the variable `word` or figuring their length an dstoring it in `wordCount`, there is no way to exit the loop.

As a quick fix I added these two lines to solve those issues:

```
word = phrase.split("\\s+");
wordCount = word.length;
```

You could also eliminate the wordCount variable entirely by checking, but I'm honestly not sure if there's value in doing that versus having the variable in use. `phrase.split("\\s+").length` in the `while` loop.

Comment: Looks like a better and shorter option, will give it a try,

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that your loop will never terminate; `wordCount` is not being updated inside of your `do...while` block.

Your *next* problem is that a `do...while` loop always runs at least once.

What you can do to fix this issue is move another instantiation of `word` into your loop body, remove the unnecessary `wordCount` variable (since it's a property of the array, and we only need it in one spot), and change your `do...while` to a `while`.

```
//input
phrase = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a three word phrase.");
String[] word = phrase.split("\\s+");

//loop for error when less than 3 words
while(word.length < 3) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error, you need to input a 3 word phrase to create a 3 letter acronym." + '\n'
            + "Please try again.");
    phrase = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a three word phrase");
    word = phrase.split("\\s+");
}
```

Comment: You should change (word.length < 3) to (word.length != 3) since that will capture lengths both under and over three words, rather than just under.

Comment: Considering that the comment implies that you want to error on less than three words, I think that `word.length < 3` is appropriate.

Comment: Thanks Makoto! I struggle with this one for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Solved

use this code -

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class ThreeLetterAcronym
{

public static void main(String args[]) 
{
    //variables
    String phrase;
    int wordCount;
    String acronym;

    //input
    phrase = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a three word phrase.");
    String [] word = phrase.split(" ");

    wordCount = word.length;        

    //loop for error when other than 3 words
        while(wordCount!=3)
        {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error, you need to input a 3 word phrase to create a 3 letter acronym." + '\n' 
                + "Please try again.");
                phrase = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a three word phrase");
        } 

    //create acronym
    acronym = Character.toString(word[0].charAt(0)).toUpperCase() + 
                 Character.toString(word[1].charAt(0)).toUpperCase() + 
                 Character.toString(word[2].charAt(0)).toUpperCase();

    //output
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The phrase you inputed is " + "." 
    + phrase + "\nYour 3 letter acronym is " + acronym + ".");

   } 
}
```